# How to display a temperature sensor value in Android application through bluetooth?

Tags: android

I am using a STS21 sensor to detect the temperature and this value should be displayed in an android application through bluetooth.Can someone tell me how to develop android app to display that temperature value.

Comment: Based on http://www.sensirion.com/en/products/humidity-temperature/temperature-sensor-sts21/ the STS21 itself doesn't have Bluetooth capabilities (it's just a sensor, which could be part of some sort of Bluetooth device): what exactly have you bought?

Comment: I'm doing a project in which foot temperature should be monitored.So for that I'm using a STS21 sensor and ATMEGA328P microprocessor .The temperature values need to be displayed in an android application through HC 05 bluetooth module.

Answer (score 2):

First, read a generic how-to Java manual, if you don't know Java. Ditto for XML, which is heavily used in Android.
Then, read a generic "how to make Android apps" tutorial, and finally look through the manual for your sensor to work out how to plug it into your code.

### Edit 1

OK, I've looked around for you (I'm not an Arduino user myself), and I've found someone who seems to have done a similar project. They describe wring up the circuit and the software they wrote. Tell me how you get on.

- [Instructables article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Andruino-A-Simple-2-Way-Bluetooth-based-Android-C/)
- [Download demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techbitar.android.Andruino)
- [Author's page](http://www.techbitar.com/ardudroid-simple-bluetooth-control-for-arduino-and-android.html)

Comment: So far what I have done is I have used Arduino UNO and with the help of it I have displayed the STS21 sensor value in Serial monitor.The part left to do is I have to display these sensor value in Android application in mobile through HC 05 blue tooth module.Please help me with this.

Comment: How are you getting on? Did you set up the system described or read through the code? I don't think It had the Android-side code given; can you work out how to write it from the Arduino code given?